# MFC Application Updating Only Current View

Tags: view, mfc, split

I divided the Main View of my VC++6 MFC application using Static Splitting with rows and columns like (1x2) or (3x3) and so on.

One of these parts, when clicked on, is the Active View.

When I draw a shape say, a circle/rectangle on the Active View, all the other Views ape the shapes I drew on the Active View. How do I avoid that?

I tried UpdateAllViews() with the Active View as first argument. It still does the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post some code? It's difficult to say without knowing anything.

Comment: The answer lies in the fact that I was using the same Document (C<classname>Doc) for the drawing of Shapes onto each splitted view of the Main Class View. When I moved the Shapes List (A List which helps iterate through the shapes drawn on image so as to Redraw them when necessary) to the View class and handled the drawing from there, it works alright (which means the other Views don't duplicate these shapes undesirably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the same class for all views this is expected behavior, since splitter wires all views to the same document object. I presume that you are use document object for drawing data storage.

UpdateAllViews is used for to update views if data in the document change. Each view then uses document’s data to render different visual interpretation of this data. Hence each view would be a different type (represented by different classes) knowing how to visualize data.

**For example:** document is used to store number array. Three views are showing those numbers as decimal, hex and binary representation.
If one number is changed, all views are notify to update own representation.

In your case working solution would be to move drawing data to the view rather than the document. Most likely your application does not need a document at all.

Answer (score 0):

UpdateAllViews() calls the OnUpdate() function for each view. The default implementation of OnUpdate() invalidates the client area (talking about simple "graphics" views like CView() or CScrollView()). You can override the OnUpdate() member and encode the desired behaviour (as far as invalidating/updating is concerned) in the lHint and/or pHint parameters.